# How to hide value 0 on Axis Vega Chart

Tags: axes, vega

I am building a vega chart. on the x-axis, I don't want to show 0 value on the axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following config to scale(**VEGA CHART**):

Config: `"nice": false,"zero": false`

Example config:

```
  "scales": [
   {
    "name": "y",
    "nice": false,
    "zero": false,
    "padding": 15
   }..]
```